# Passing the data from UIKit view controller to Swift UI View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftui, uiviewcontroller

I have the function navigate the form one to another view tableview cell selection. I am wondering how can I pass the data form ui View controller table view cell selection to Swift UI view.

Here is details struct.

```
struct FruitsDetails {
    let genus, name: String
}
```

Here is the function I use to navigate to the view and working, but I need help to pass the data ...

```
func goToFruitsDetails(fruitsDetails: FruitsDetails) {
    let vm =  FruitsDetailsViewModel(fruitsDetails: fruitsDetails)
    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI())
    navController.pushViewController(hostingController, animated: true)
 }
```

Here is the table view did select function .

```
extension FruitesViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let fruit = viewModel?.getFruitsDetails(for: indexPath.row) else { return }
        coordinator?.goToFruitsDetails(fruitsDetails: fruit)
        // Need suggestion or help to pass the data 
    }
}
```

Here is the UI view code. I did not write anything yet.

```
import SwiftUI

struct FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI: View {
    var fruitsDetailsViewModel: FruitsDetailsViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Fruit Name in Swift UI: \(fruitsDetailsViewModel.fruitsDetails.name)")
        Text("Fruit Genus in Swift UI: \(fruitsDetailsViewModel.fruitsDetails.genus)")
    }
}

struct FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    let fruitsDetails = FruitsDetails(genus: "Some", name: "Thing")
    init(fruitsDetails: FruitsDetails) {
        self.fruitsDetails = fruitsDetails
    }
    let viewModel = FruitsDetailsViewModel(fruitsDetails: fruitsDetails)
    static var previews: some View {         FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI(fruitsDetailsViewModel: viewModel)

    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the error .
[image]

Comment: At minimum, you're going to need some variable in `FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI` to hold whatever data you want to give it. As far as *I did not write anything yet* -- why not? Give it your best shot -- you'll probably figure out more than you expect, and we'll have more to work with if you still end up stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `viewModel` you declared to the actual SwiftUI View. i.e  in your `goToFruitsDetails` function where you declare your `viewModel` you need to pass it to `FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI`. In `FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI` you can declare a `var viewModel` and simply pass it in the init.

```
struct FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI: View {
   var viewModel: FruitsDetailsViewModel

   var body: some View {
      Text("Fruit Name in Swift UI: \(fruitsDetailsViewModel.fruitsDetails.name)")
      Text("Fruit Genus in Swift UI: \(fruitsDetailsViewModel.fruitsDetails.genus)")
   }
 }

struct FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI_Previews: PreviewProvider { 
    static var previews: some View {
        let fruit = FruitsDetails(genus: "Some", name: "Thing") 
        let viewModel = FruitsDetailsViewModel(fruitsDetail: fruit)
        FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI(viewModel: viewModel) 
    }
}

func goToFruitsDetails(fruitsDetails: FruitsDetails) {
    let vm =  FruitsDetailsViewModel(fruitsDetails: fruitsDetails)
    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI(viewModel: vm))
    navController.pushViewController(hostingController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: the will be passed from table view cell didselect function

Comment: Please pay more attention to my response. This is the line where you pass the viewModel

`let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI(viewModel: vm))`

Comment: Ok if you say to pass the view model object into function then it should not show error into preview of the Swift UI View although I pass the view model object into function .

Comment: It saying Cannot find 'fruitsDetailsViewModel' in scope

Comment: Passing the `fruitsDetailsViewModel` in preview won't work because it's out of its scope. But try passing an initialised viewModel there. Try this @Mohammad

`struct FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    let fruit = FruitsDetails(genus: "Some", name: "Thing")
    let viewModel = FruitsDetailsViewModel(fruitsDetail: fruit)
    static var previews: some View {
        FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI(fruitsDetailsViewModel: viewModel)
    }
}`

Comment: Here is the error ..Cannot use instance member 'fruitsDetails' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: init(fruitsDetails: FruitsDetails) {
        self.fruitsDetails = fruitsDetails
    }

Comment: I added the initialiser

Comment: I think at this point is pretty hard to follow the errors without seeing more of your code. Let me know if you get it to work :)

Comment: ok Let me add itt

Comment: Updated please check it now

Comment: Please take a closer look to my code. It's all in there:
1. You need to declare the viewModel in the FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI
2. You need to pass the viewModel when you create the `FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI` , so in the init. In the `goToFruitsDetails` - I provided the code.
3. Paste the code I provided for the preview
You are all good to go, but take it line by line and try to understand it.

Comment: Let me double check again

Comment: Please correct the code , The problem was this two line should be after static var previews: some View {
        let viewModel = FruitsDetailsViewModel(fruitsDetails: FruitsDetails(genus: "Some", name: "Thing"))

        FruitDetailsViewSwiftUI(viewModel: viewModel)
    }

Comment: Glad it worked. Would you please mark my response as accepted?